# What is the meaing of "(.text+0x26c4)" means in fortran linking error message?

Tags: fortran, linker-errors, gfortran, undefined-reference

I am using gfortran compiler and ld linker in LINUX ubuntu 16.04.
When I am compiling some program written in Fortran 77, I have the following error message:

```
libdist.a(setup.F.o): In function `setup_':
setup.F:(.text+0x26c4): undefined reference to `mpi_send_'
setup.F:(.text+0x2b3c): undefined reference to `mpi_recv_'
setup.F:(.text+0x7984): undefined reference to `mpi_send_'
setup.F:(.text+0xb107): undefined reference to `mpi_recv_'
```

I guess it is about the position of error. However, it is difficult to me the find where is the error.

Can I have a better presentation of the position of error? Such as the c/cxx error: "setup.F:15:12: "

Comment: Try including the compiler option `-g` in your compilation command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an address. And is is NOT a Fortran error. It is a linker error. You can get the very same error from a C or C++ code or any other compiled code linked by the same linker.

Generate debugging symbols (compiler option `-g` or `-ggdb` or similar - consult Debugging options in the GCC Fortran manual) to get something more meaningful. But if you do that you will realize that it only points you to some location where you do:

```
  call mpi_send(...)
```

in some subroutine or function called `setup()`.

So, it is not terribly useful in this case. The important thing is that you should link the appropriate MPI library. Normally that is done by calling `mpif90` or `mpifort` or a similar wrapper which is called *instead of `gfortran`*. Consult the documentation of your MPI library implementation.